# Wordpress nested if is_active_sidebar within another is_active_sidebar

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a theme that displays a menu of products via widgets.  We are able to show/hide these categories (sidebars) via the code below.  Right now it will show/hide this carousel-item if one of the two product categories have widgets.  We would like keep this functionality, but hide the category if it is empty. For example if there are products in category 1, but not in category 2 we want to hide an entire section (see notes in code of where we want this.

```
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'widget-category-1' ) || is_active_sidebar('widget-category-2') ) { ?>
        <div class="carousel-item active animated fadeIn">
            <div class="d-block w-100">

                //show or hide start here//
                <div class="container-fluid px-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="three-col">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-category-1' ); ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                //show or hide end here//

                //show or hide start here//
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="three-col">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-category-2' ); ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                //show or hide end here//

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) or nth-of-type to reference the element you want to toggle. That or possibly a [not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class should do the trick.

I added a CSS tag to your question. You would need to add the rest of the element that dynamic_sidebar is returning to be sure but typically there is a 'has-items' identifier you can reference.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of going CSS route for this.  The dynamic_sidebar returns <li> </li> for each item.  Based on how we are doings things though I think if I can keep it in the PHP side of things it would be quicker in this scenario.

Comment: Yes. There should already be rules in your theme ready for those 'has-items' tags. In fact it might help to look at the elements that are toggled in the stylesheet to sort out how the widget displays the categories.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  We couldn't use css with the not()/:empty pseudo due to <ul></ul> having white space, but this helped point us in the direction of the route we went.  We ended up using javascript.

Comment: Yes. I see you answered your own question. =|

Answer (score 0):

We ended up wrapping each section in a `<div class="phide"></div>` and used javascript to hide the this div if no  `<li></li>`  is present

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.phide:not(:has(li))').hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```